# Is my inner tube too big?

Tags: tire, innertube

So I punctured my inner tube (again) and I usually buy 700 x 25/32C inner tube for my 700 x 28 tire. Which fitted nicely. But, I felt like the brand I was using wasn't the best so I switched it out and got a Contrast 700 x 28C inner tube (as stated on Amazon) but when it arrived, it was a Vavert 700 x 28/32C which looked too big for my tire.

Will the 28/32 fit in my 28 tires?

Comment: The 28/32 notation implies that it will fit anywhere between those two numbers (inclusive).

Comment: Inner tubes are generally speaking quite forgiving, you can use both tubes that are slightly too small or slightly too big. Don't expect to succeed with a 20" road bike tube (is that even a thing?) in a 29" fat bike, but other than that you'll normally be fine...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely yes, you can fit that tube just fine.

The limit where you can no longer fit the inner tube to your tire is that the tube becomes wrinkled and you cannot remove those wrinkles no matter how hard you try.

Actually it's beneficial to use as big tube as you can fit there. If the tube doesn't stretch much, it probably is somewhat harder to puncture and also leaks naturally air less than a small and much-stretched tube, so you don't have to pump up the tire as often due to air leakage.

I have found that on my 622-28 (700 x 28 in other notation) Continental GP5000 tyres, I can fit a 32/47 tube just fine.

Note that occasionally, there's a trend that a manufacturer makes a 27mm tire and calls it 28mm. It reduces weight so everyone goes and buys that tire. Then another manufacturer goes in to the same game, making a 26mm tire and calling it 28mm. A third manufacturer then decides to call a 25mm tire a 28mm tire. The end result is that tires can be much narrower and lighter than what their specification says. [More about that.](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html#dishonest)

However,  I don't believe the dishonest size labels are currently actively used so you can be reasonably certain that a 28mm tire in fact is a 28mm tire. Maybe it's 27mm, maybe 29mm, depending on the rim but it's intended to be 28mm.

Also an observation: if the tube you get is really 28-32C, that sounds too narrow a range. Schwalbe's 28mm tube doesn't fit just 28-32C, it fits 28-47C. This could be an indication that your tube is not from a reputable brand.

Furthermore, I heavily suggest you to patch punctured tubes instead of buying new ones. Tubes aren't single-use-only.